# In Azure SQL Server can the AD Admin which is also a Service Principal run a query on the master database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

Given:

1. An Azure SQL Server - `MyAzureSqlServer`
2. A Service Principal - `MyServicePrincipal`
3. The Service Principal is configured as the AD Admin of the Azure SQL Server. (Azure Portal and Az Powershell module do not allow it, but Azure CLI and the REST API do)

I have Powershell code that runs `SELECT 1` on the given database in the aforementioned Azure SQL Server:

```
param($db)

$AzContext = Get-AzContext               # Assume this returns the Az Context for MyServicePrincipal
$TenantId = $AzContext.Tenant.Id
$ClientId = $AzContext.Account.Id
$SubscriptionId = $AzContext.Subscription.Id
$ClientSecret = $AzContext.Account.ExtendedProperties.ServicePrincipalSecret

$token = Get-AzureAuthenticationToken -TenantID $TenantId -ClientID $ClientId -ClientSecret $ClientSecret -ResourceAppIDUri "https://database.windows.net/"

Invoke-SqlQueryThruAdoNet -ConnectionString "Server=MyAzureSqlServer.database.windows.net;database=$db" -AccessToken $token -Query "SELECT 1"
```

Where `Get-AzureAuthenticationToken` is:

```
function Get-AzureAuthenticationToken(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$TenantID,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$ClientID,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$ClientSecret,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$ResourceAppIDUri)
{
    $tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -UseBasicParsing `
        -Uri "https://login.windows.net/$TenantID/oauth2/token" `
        -Body @{
        resource      = $ResourceAppIDUri
        client_id     = $ClientID
        grant_type    = 'client_credentials'
        client_secret = $ClientSecret
    } -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

    Write-Verbose "Access token type is $($tokenResponse.token_type), expires $($tokenResponse.expires_on)"
    $tokenResponse.access_token
}
```

And `Invoke-SqlQueryThruAdoNet` is:

```
function Invoke-SqlQueryThruAdoNet(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$ConnectionString,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Query,
    $QueryTimeout = 30,
    [string]$AccessToken
)
{
    $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection                
    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    try 
    {
        $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
        if ($AccessToken)
        {
            $SqlConnection.AccessToken = $AccessToken
        }
        $SqlConnection.Open()

        $SqlCmd.CommandTimeout = $QueryTimeout
        $SqlCmd.CommandText = $Query
        $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

        $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
        $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd        
        [void]$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

        $res = $null
        if ($DataSet.Tables.Count)
        {
            $res = $DataSet.Tables[$DataSet.Tables.Count - 1]
        }
        $res
    }
    finally 
    {
        $SqlAdapter.Dispose()
        $SqlCmd.Dispose()
        $SqlConnection.Dispose()
    }
}
```

And it works fine on any database, except on the master, for which I get:

> [MyAzureSqlServer.database.windows.net\master] Login failed for user '4...1@2...b'. (SqlError 18456, LineNumber = 65536, ClientConnectionId = b8f4f657-2772-4306-b222-4533013227d1)

where `4...1` is the client Id of `MyServicePrincipal` and `2...b` is our Azure AD Tenant Id.

So I know the access token is OK, because I can run queries on other databases. It is specifically the `master` that is problematic. Is there a solution for that? Of course, it must work with the Service Principal being the AD Admin.

**EDIT 1**

As I have mentioned there are 2 ways to configure a Service Principal to be the AD Admin:

- Using Azure CLI. It is actually straightforward:

```
az sql server ad-admin create --resource-group {YourAzureSqlResourceGroupName} `
        --server-name {YourAzureSqlServerName} `
        --display-name {ADAdminName} `
        --object-id {ServicePrincipalObjectId}
```

The `{ADAdminName}` can be whatever, but we pass the display name of the Service Principal.

Now while this works, we abandoned Azure CLI in favour of Az Powershell, because the latter does not persist Service Principal credentials on disk in clear text. However, Az Powershell's function [Set-AzSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/set-azsqlserveractivedirectoryadministrator?view=azps-4.1.0) does not accept a Service Principal. Yet the Azure REST API does allow it, hence we have the following custom PS function doing the job:

```
function Set-MyAzSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator
{
    [CmdLetBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'NoObjectId')]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0)][string]$ResourceGroupName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 1)][string]$ServerName,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ObjectId', Mandatory)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$ObjectId,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ObjectId', Mandatory)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$DisplayName
    )

    $AzContext = Get-AzContext
    if (!$AzContext)
    {
        throw "No Az context is found."
    }
    $TenantId = $AzContext.Tenant.Id
    $ClientId = $AzContext.Account.Id
    $SubscriptionId = $AzContext.Subscription.Id
    $ClientSecret = $AzContext.Account.ExtendedProperties.ServicePrincipalSecret

    if ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'NoObjectId')
    {
        $sp = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $ClientId
        $DisplayName = $sp.DisplayName
        $ObjectId = $sp.Id
    }

    $path = "/subscriptions/$SubscriptionId/resourceGroups/$ResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/$ServerName/administrators/activeDirectory"
    $apiUrl = "https://management.azure.com${path}?api-version=2014-04-01"    
    $jsonBody = @{
        id         = $path
        name       = 'activeDirectory'
        properties = @{
            administratorType = 'ActiveDirectory'
            login             = $DisplayName
            sid               = $ObjectId
            tenantId          = $TenantId
        }
    } | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99
    $token = Get-AzureAuthenticationToken -TenantID $TenantId -ClientID $ClientId -ClientSecret $ClientSecret -ResourceAppIDUri "https://management.core.windows.net/"
    $headers = @{
        "Authorization" = "Bearer $token"
        "Content-Type"  = "application/json" 
    }
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    Invoke-RestMethod $apiUrl -Method Put -Headers $headers -Body $jsonBody
}
```

It uses the already familiar (see above) function `Get-AzureAuthenticationToken`. For our needs it sets the currently logged in Service Principal as the AD admin.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you configure service principal as Azure AD AD admin?

Comment: Please, see EDIT 1.

Comment: Is it useful for you?

Comment: Let me comment on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to my test, when we directly set Azure service principal as Azure SQL AD admin, it will cause some problems. We cannot log in `master` database with the service pricipal. Because Azure AD administrator login should be an Azure AD user or an Azure AD group. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-overview#administrator-structure)

So if you want to set Azure service principal as Azure SQL AD admin, we need to create an Azure AD security group, add service principal as the group's member the set the Azure AD group as Azure SQL AD admin.

For example

1. Configure Azure AD admin

```
Connect-AzAccount

$group=New-AzADGroup -DisplayName SQLADADmin -MailNickname SQLADADmin 

$sp=Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName "TodoListService-OBO-sample-v2"

Add-AzADGroupMember -MemberObjectId $sp.Id -TargetGroupObjectId $group.id

$sp=Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName "<your sq name>"

Remove-AzSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator -ResourceGroupName "<>" -ServerName "<>" -force

Set-AzSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator -ResourceGroupName "<>" -ServerName "<>" -DisplayName $group.DisplayName -ObjectId $group.id
```

[image]

query

```
$appId = "<your sp app id>"
$password = "<your sp password>"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($appId, $secpasswd)
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $mycreds -Tenant "<your AD tenant id>"
#get token
$context =Get-AzContext
$dexResourceUrl='https://database.windows.net/'
$token = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, 
                                $context.Environment, 
                                $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(),
                                 $null, 
                                 [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, 
                                 $null, $dexResourceUrl).AccessToken

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection                
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$ConnectionString="Data Source=testsql08.database.windows.net; Initial Catalog=master;"

# query the current database name
$Query="SELECT DB_NAME()"

    try 
    {
        $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
        if ($token)
        {
            $SqlConnection.AccessToken = $token
        }
        $SqlConnection.Open()

        $SqlCmd.CommandText = $Query
        $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

        $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
        $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd        
        [void]$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

        $res = $null
        if ($DataSet.Tables.Count)
        {
            $res = $DataSet.Tables[$DataSet.Tables.Count - 1]
        }
         $res
    }
    finally 
    {
        $SqlAdapter.Dispose()
        $SqlCmd.Dispose()
        $SqlConnection.Dispose()
    }
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but I will wait for other answers, because here the AD admin is a group, not a Service Principal. We cannot use this approach, because every pod is deployed with a dedicated Service Principal. The code that creates the SP does not have permissions to modify AD groups.

Comment: @mark Could you please tell me why you need to modify AD groups?

Comment: Because when we bootstrap a new pod a dedicated service principal is created. The bootstrapping code has permissions to create a new service principal, but not to modify any existing AD groups or create new ones.